# Have to delete environment variables for aws cli to work without --profile flag

Tags: amazon-web-services

ok so I am baffled by this aws cli behavior. Basically what is going on is that when I set my AWS creds related in environment variable, AWS CLI forces me to pass --profile flag each time I use the CLI.

So basically when `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` AND `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` then I cannot run commands like `aws s3 ls` without passing --profile flag to it even though my profile is [default]

Also, jus to note the environment variable values and the values inside my `/.aws/credentials`
file is exactly same. Also, I tried to set both `AWS_PROFILE` and `AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE` to default hoping that if all values such as keys,secret and profile are set in environment variable then I do not have to pass any --profile flag explicitly. Not having to pass this flag explicitly is very important for me at this point because if I am running an application which connects with aws and picks up default credentials, there is no easy way to pass profile information to that app.

my credentials file look like following:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = AKIA****
aws_secret_access_key = VpR***
```

My config file looks like following:

```
[default]
region = us-west-1
output = json
```

And my environment variables do have the same values for corresponding entries. for key, secret and profile at least.

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Comment: How does you `~/.aws/config` look like? How do you environment variables look like?

Comment: You should set both AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, or neither. There's no situation in which setting just one of them is useful. This works fine and you should not have to provide the `--profile` option. You need to double-check that you have actually set the values correctly in your environment.

Comment: @Dunedan, I updated my question with the information that you asked for.

Comment: @jarmod I did have both set up. I am removing OR part from my question to alleviate any further confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The AWS CLI looks for credentials using a series of providers in a particular order. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html#config-settings-and-precedence)

Specifically:

```
Command line options – You can specify --region, --output, and --profile as parameters on the command line.

Environment variables – You can store values in the environment variables: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, and AWS_SESSION_TOKEN. If they are present, they are used.

CLI credentials file – This is one of the files that is updated when you run the command aws configure. The file is located at ~/.aws/credentials on Linux or macOS, or at C:\Users\USERNAME\.aws\credentials on Windows. This file can contain the credential details for the default profile and any named profiles.

CLI configuration file – This is another file that is updated when you run the command aws configure. The file is located at ~/.aws/config on Linux or macOS, or at C:\Users\USERNAME\.aws\config on Windows. This file contains the configuration settings for the default profile and any named profiles.

Container credentials – You can associate an IAM role with each of your Amazon Elastic Container Service (Amazon ECS) task definitions. Temporary credentials for that role are then available to that task's containers. For more information, see IAM Roles for Tasks in the Amazon Elastic Container Service Developer Guide.

Instance profile credentials – You can associate an IAM role with each of your Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) instances. Temporary credentials for that role are then available to code running in the instance. The credentials are delivered through the Amazon EC2 metadata service. For more information, see IAM Roles for Amazon EC2 in the Amazon EC2 User Guide for Linux Instances and Using Instance Profiles in the IAM User Guide.
```

Another potential option for you would be to `unset` any colliding variables in your env and rely on the aws credentials file to provide the appropriate access credentials from the `default` entry.

Comment: With that understanding, IF profile, key and secret are st in environment variable then it should know which profile to use and should not ask me to provide --profile information each time. Correct?

Comment: I don't think you need to set the profile in the env, but otherwise that is correct. If AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY are set in your env, they will be used before the credentials file and you should not need to specify a profile. One thing I sometimes forget to do is `export` the credentials so they are available to subsequent commands from the same environment. Also, make sure the variable names are capitalized in your env, which is different than how they are named in the credentials file.

Comment: I did actually export and then echoed back to make sure that they are correctly set up. Just that the behavior surprised me a little bit after setting them

Comment: Just to confirm, the variables in your env are upper case? Can you post the output of running `env` (masking sensitive entries as necessary).

Comment: @work_as_coded: Your comment helped figure out what the problem was. In reality there were additional AWS enviroment variable set called `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` and `AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN` in addition to key and secret. which were not associated with this `default` profile but another profile which uses STS kind of tokens. as soon as aws saw these values set, it assumed some STS style auth/profile which was obviously wrong. As soon as I did unset on session token and security token my aws cli started working as expected

Comment: where is the environment variables coming from, otherwards how does the environment variables are set?

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out @Lost. Can you accept?